# C# Entity Framework Core after SaveChangesAsync does not save

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper

I have faced with strange issue that when I update using reflection some `entity` after save this `entity` resets to previous state ...

But consider the follwoing code:

```cs
var savedEntity = await _dbContext.Places.FindAsync(1);
var updateEntity = await _dbContext.Places.Persist(_mapper).InsertOrUpdateAsync(model); // Custom method that is use a lot reflaction, but return updated savedEntity
bool isTheSame = ReferenceEquals(savedEntity, updateEntity); // true

...

await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(); // <-- After this line updateEntity resets to previous state
```

In this example after `SaveChangesAsync` in `updateEntity` that equals by reference to savedEntity list property resets to previous state ...
That is very strange, because I have updated existing entity, but seems like _dbContext does not know that I have updated the model ...

Inside of the `InsertOrUpdateAsync` I only search for existing entity and add new entity to DbSet ...
There is no magic, but there are lots of code that is why I did not added it here ...

But anyway, it works but in some special cases like this where I have in list property Many-to-Many relationship it does not ... but want is strange for previous update of list with many-to-many relationship it works, but for second time it does not ... (

Comment: It's quite likely that the problem is caused by some of your custom code that you are not yet sharing, please share the full context, that will help us find the problem.

Comment: Until you share the code: the dbcontext should not be reused. You should be disposing it and creating another one "often". Also, I usually avoid any "attach for update" patterns. Instead, it's more reliable and standard to read the record fresh from the db, apply the changes from the view model to the model, then Save Changes.

Comment: @Todd Okay, I will try to create simple sample code ... But anyway I cannot get why when I update existing model framework does not save code ... It is pretty strange, seems like I do not understand update mechanic under Entity Framework Core ...